# Shift of A martingale by A stopping time

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes, martingales, stopping-times

In Karatzas&Shreve Brownian Motion and Stochastic Calculus Problem 3.27: Let $T$ be a bounded stopping time of the filtration $\left\{ \mathscr{F}_{t}\right\} $, which satisfies the usual conditions, and define $\mathscr{\widetilde{F}}_{t}=\mathscr{F}_{T+t}$. Then $\left\{ \mathscr{\widetilde{F}}_{t}\right\} $ also satisfies the usual conditions. And if $\left\{ \widetilde{X}_{t},\mathscr{\widetilde{F}}_{t}:0\le t<\infty\right\}$  is a right-continuous submartingale with $\widetilde{X}_{0}=0$, a.s. P, then $\left\{ X_{t}=\widetilde{X}_{\max\left\{ 0,t-T\right\} },\mathscr{F}_{t}:0\le t<\infty\right\}$  is also a submartingale.

I have solved this problem except one part. My question is that: how can we show that $\widetilde{X}_{\max\left\{ 0,t-T\right\} }$ is adapted $\left\{ \mathscr{F}_{t}\right\}$.

Answer (score 1):

The $\widetilde{X}_{(t−T)^+}$  is adapted $\{\mathscr{F}_t\} $, it could be proved as follows.

1. If $ U $ is a $(\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_t)$ stopping time, then $T+U$ is  an $(\mathscr{F}_t)$ stopping time and 
   $$ \widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_U\subset \mathscr{F}_{T+U}. \tag{*}$$ 
   The proof could be verified according the definition of stopping time and 
   $ \widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_U $.
2. If $ S $  is an $(\mathscr{F}_t)$ stopping time, then $ (S-T)^+ $ is
   a $(\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_t)$ stopping time and 
   $$ \widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_{(S-T)^+}\subset \mathscr{F}_{T+(S-T)^+}
   =\mathscr{F}_{S\vee T}.\tag{1}  $$

   *Proof*  For $ t\ge 0 $,
   $$ \{(S-T)^+\le t\}=\{S\le T+t\} \in \mathscr{F}_{T+t}=
   \widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_t, 
   $$
   so $ (S-T)^+ $ is a $(\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_t)$ stopping time and (1)  follows from (*). Q.E.D.

From (1) it is easy to obtain the following
$$ 1_{(S>T)}\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_{(S-T)^+} \subset  1_{(S>T)}\mathscr{F}_{S\vee T} \subset \mathscr{F}_S, \tag{2} $$
where $1_{(S>T)}\mathscr{F}_{S\vee T} = \{1_{(S>T)}\xi: \xi \text{ is an } \mathscr{F}_{S\vee T}-\text{measurable variable}\}.$

Now taking $ S=t $ in (2) we could get 
$$  \widetilde{X}_{(t−T)^+}=1_{(t>T)} \widetilde{X}_{(t−T)^+} \in \mathscr{F}_t . $$

Comment: But I have trouble showing your result in (1). Could you please be more specific?

Comment: @Joesf.Albert Thank you for your replication. I already add a proof of (1).

Answer (score 0):

- If $t\le T$, $X_{t}=0$. 
  So knowing all the past before $t$ allows you to know $X$ until that time.
- If $t\ge T$, $X_{t}=\widetilde{X}_{t-T}$. 
  So knowing all the past before $t$ for the filtration $\mathscr{{F}}$ allows you to know all the past before $t-T$ for the filtration $\mathscr{\widetilde{F}}$, which allows you to know $\widetilde X$ until time $t-T$ and therefore $X$ until time $t$.

Formally, let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})$ and $t\ge T$. We need to prove that $\left\{X_t\in A\right\}\in\mathscr{F}_t$:

\begin{alignat*}{2}
\left\{\omega\in\Omega, X_t(\omega)\in A\right\} = \left\{\omega\in\Omega, \widetilde X_{t-T}(\omega)\in A\right\}
\end{alignat*}
but $\left\{\widetilde X_{t-T}\in A\right\}$ is $\widetilde{\mathscr{F}}_{t-T}$-measurable, which means it is $\mathscr{F}_{t}$-measurable or equivalently $\left\{X_t\in A\right\}\in\mathscr{F}_t$.

Comment: But how can we prove it in rigorous mathematical proof?

Comment: The answer is completed, does it look ok?